# Hostgator - 404 error when trying to use .htaccess to redirect to multiple sites?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two sites which I am trying to host on the same plan. Site1 is stored in a folder called site1.com. Site2 is stored in a folder called site2.com.

- public_html

  - site1.com
  - site2.com

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # Rewrite all requests for site1 to the site1.com subdirectory
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site1\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site1.com/$1 [NC]

   # Rewrite all requests for site2 to the site2.com subdirectory
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site2.com/$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

I can access site1.com fine. But I get a 404 error when I try to access site2.com. I don't understand why because the rules are exactly the same for each site.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to show different sites when using parked domains, which is not advised when using the Hatchling plan. The other plans should accomodate different sites automatically, yes?

Comment: Why is it not advised? I am not expecting much traffic at all for either sites, and it will save spending more on another plan.

Comment: @Mike Rockett Also I have the Baby plan which supports multiple domains.

Comment: Plans that support only one domain are like that for a reason - I am sure that serving different sites on such plans would be against the terms of service. If you are using a plan that supports multiple domains, then you should be using addon domains, and it should point to the correct directory anyway, hence you would not need to use `.htaccess`.